# -fPIC error when linking static and dynamic libs with GCC

Tags: gcc, shared-libraries, static-libraries, ld

I have written a small code that I want to compile with a combination of static and dynamic libs. The code uses functions from hdf5 and exodusII (a specialist CAE lib) as well as math, and of course good-old stdio.

To make the binary highly portable, I wanted to link hdf5 and exodusII statically into the code, but leave math and libc as shared, so that the code is optimised on different platforms.

I cannot work out what the correct method is to compile something like this. I already have tried:

```
gcc -lm -lc -fPIC test1.c /usr/lib/libexodus.a /usr/lib/libhdf5.a -Wl,-pie
```

This gives the error:

> ```
> /usr/lib64/crt1.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against '__libc_csu_fini' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
> /usr/lib64/crt1.o: could not read symbols: Bad value
> ```

I have also tried:

```
gcc -c test1.c (WORKS!)
ld /usr/lib/libhdf5.a /usr/lib/libexodus.a -lm -lc test1.o
```

Which gives a warning of not being able to find an entry symbol `_start` followed by a whole lot of undefined reference errors to the libexodus functions in *test1.c*. (I have checked *libexodus.a* with `nm`, and the functions being reported do actually exist in the archive.

I would really appreciate a hand in this. I am not overly experienced in using static libs, but for this application, I think it is the best choice, so long as I can work out a reliable way of compiling and linking.

Comment: "WORKS!" Not really. Search "link order" on this site.

Comment: thanks @n.m., I was just meaning that the compile of test1.c without any linking worked fine, but the subsequent ld script did not work.
Thankyou for your suggestions, I have been reading about linking orders in quite a few posts, and now worked out where I went wrong.

Comment: For the linker, specify all objects first, then libraries in the dependency order. If library A uses library B, A should come before B in the list.

Comment: And don't do -pie because your libraries are probably not PIC.

Comment: @n.m. thanks again. I explicitly compiled the exodus, netcdf and hdf5 libs using -fPIC (I have documented the build of these libs here: http://bc247.wordpress.com/tutorials/building-exodusii/), but libcurl, libdl, libmath and glibc all came precompiled from the package manager. Are these precompiled libs usually compiled using -fPIC? Will there be any problems if they were not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was in the linking order. I have now learned that the linking order works like babushka dolls where the library at the top of the dependency tree comes first, and the most general library comes last.

For future reference, in the end, the working build command was as follows:

```
gcc test1.c -lexodus -lnetcdf -lhdf5_hl -hdf5 -lcurl -ldl -lm
```

What I don't really understand is that when I had built the exodus library as a shared library, I only had to link against the shared library, and the dependency libraries (`-lnetcdf -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lcurl`) were not specified; however, with the static compilation of the exact same library, I now need to link all the libraries explicitly.

If someone has an answer to this behaviour, it would be helpful for my understanding and very appreciated, but as I can continue coding with this current build method, it is not an urgent matter.